# Why do I get System.UnauthorizedAccessException Access to the path 'Google.Apis.Auth' is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, google-drive-api

I have implemented google drive functionality for file management its working fine in local system but whenever i hosted it on Godaddy server it throw following error

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException
>       Access to the path 'Google.Apis.Auth' is denied.

Following code i am using :

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
   new ClientSecrets
   {
       ClientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GDriveClientId"],//Get ClientID from web.config.
       ClientSecret = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GDriveClientSecret"]//Get ClientSecret from web.config.
   },
   new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GDriveCreatedByUser"],//Get UserName from web.config.
   CancellationToken.None).Result;

return credential;
```

I am using VS2010,IIS 7 for above functionality

Comment: How about sharing the line of code that caused this exception (and maybe its configuration?)

Comment: Above UserCredential related code i am using for that

Comment: And it fails on that line?

Comment: @John : this issue is coming on godaddy.com server its working fine in local environment

Comment: @rene : yes its fails on that line.

Comment: Does GoDaddy allow outgoing connections? Is a firewall preventing you the connection because it requires you to authenticate?

Comment: yes rene. authentication of google drive service is working in GoDaddy server

Answer (score 8):

Expanding what Chandrika has already said, the ASP.NET user needs read and write permissions to the Google API Client OAuth2 Library's permanent storage folder .

Its default value is a folder named "Google.Apis.Auth" in `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` (which usually corresponds to `C:\Users\your-user-name\AppData\Roaming`).

Alternatively, another folder can be provided as the last parameter of the [`GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()`](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4/OAuth2/GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs) method:

```cs
var folder = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/MyGoogleStorage");

UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
   new ClientSecrets
   {
       ClientId = "PutYourClientIdHere",
       ClientSecret = "PutYourClientSecretHere"
   },
   new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
   "user",
   CancellationToken.None,
   new FileDataStore(folder)).Result;

return credential;
```

See: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#credentials and https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Comment: Adding to the Google credentials call the 5th parameter 'new FileDataStore(folder)' solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I added that folder as a relative path, and code hangs at `AuthorizeAsync` method. Any idea?

Comment: What is that `GDriveCreatedByUser`?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati the third parameter is the key that the OpenAuth API uses to see if there's already a TokenResponse available in the store (mostly like a cache key). Actually the name I have used might be confusing, I have updated the example, now it should be more clear.

Comment: Even doing this throws the exception, can there be any more reasons? I have also tried an in-memory data store that doesn't even interact with any file but still throws the same Access Denied issue.

Comment: i have also tried above sample but getting "Access Denied" error any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3):

Root cause of the problem : This issue is generated because after validating authentication request its create directory and token file under in window's user's folder 
and we have not right's for that folder of Godadday server so it was not working

Solution : Modified the source code of google apis[`filedatasource.cs`] for creating that file inside our directory and add reference of it and it will work

Comment: sample code please? i have tried with 
var googleaccesstoken = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/MyGoogleStorage"); but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find a solution here: [Deploying ASP.NET to Windows Azure cloud, application gives error when running on cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033924/deploying-asp-net-to-windows-azure-cloud-application-gives-error-when-running-o).

You just need to configure your IIS to work with the FileDataStore.

The following is copied from the answer there:

A.If you have RDP Acces to the Azure cloud then change the IIS settings

```
1.Go to the IIS
2.Under sites select the Default site
3.Add Permission
4.choose I_User object and give read/write access.
5.later you can automate this setting using a batch file and startup task.
```

B.I think you are using any local path. You should change this to local storage for temporary requirement and blob storage for long requirement.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your valuable response. 
                    
my issue is solved and now its working fine in also GoDadday server after modified source code of api of google drive

Comment: What did you have to change?

Comment: Change "Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData" with "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("YourFolderName")" in this line                                                  folderPath=Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), folder);

Comment: @ChandrikaPrajapati I tried to do the integration as you said. But I get an Access Denied error in this. Do you have any idea why it is coming like this.