# How to resolve Permission issue with Google.Apis.Auth

Tags: asp.net, google-drive-api

I have created a website in `asp.net` to store uploaded files on Google Drive using [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/).

Everything works fine on local machine, but on my server when I am accessing my site for drive functionality, I am getting the following Error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'Google.Apis.Auth' is denied.
```

My authentication code:

```
var driveCredential =
          GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets {ClientId = CLIENT_ID,ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET, }
         ,new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive }
         ,"user@gmail.com"
         ,CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

How to resolve this Issue ?

Comment: When I host my Application on IIS then also getting same exception message :-  System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'Google.Apis.Auth' is denied.

Comment: you also have an extra "," after CLIENT_SECRET (probably unrelated to this issue)

Comment: When we create virtual directory then only face this issue.

Comment: I miss read the error deleted my previous comment.  Sounds like permissions issue. have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405767/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-access-to-the-path-google-apis-auth-is-deni

Comment: I don't have any idea about --  var folder = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/MyGoogleStorage");

Comment: My code work when run using visual studio locally but when Host on IIS then getting exception message.