# Google Calendar API Token access

Tags: google-contacts-api

I have created a google calendar app using Visual studio. It all works fine in visual studio with saved credentials . When I run the program ( Web) the google token is saved to C:\program files(86)\Token1.json

However If I try to run outside Visual studio as normal web delivery it says access denied to token1.json.
I assume its trying to find the token in a different location. Any ideas how I find where its looking for it so as I can give folder permissions?

Answer (score 1):

found an answer which works, had to add my own folder within app_data for my tokens
[Why do I get System.UnauthorizedAccessException Access to the path 'Google.Apis.Auth' is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405767/why-do-i-get-system-unauthorizedaccessexception-access-to-the-path-google-apis)

Comment: I upvoted you as your new here and we do need fresh new questions and answers. But pls do read the [faq] and see if future quesstions fit this site. This seems specific to an API and also seems it was already asnwered... be a bit more mindful